# Make one column of jtable non-ediatble using netbeans design center

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

**I want to make one column of jTable non-ediatble using netbeans**

code:

```
public void setResultSets(ResultSet rs1){
      jTable4.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));

      jTable4.setRowHeight(50);
      jTable4.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 18)); 
      jTable4.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(265);
      jTable4.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(266);
     jTable4.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    }
```

i have tried:

```
jTable4.setEnabled(false);
```

but it is not working.

This is the code generated by netbeans :

```
Table4 = new javax.swing.JTable();

jTable4.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
));

jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable4);
```

Comment: You'll need to create your own model, one that extends DefaultTableModel would be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: and override the `isCellEditable(...)` method to return `false` for your column index.

Comment: I am simply using drag and drop , is there a way i can do these ? Thanks anyways

Comment: Yes, don't use "drag and drop" -- write some *code*. What's stopping you from doing this?

Comment: @AnshumanDube Short answer - no; Long answer, roll up your selves and get your hands dirty by writing some code

Comment: Ok ill try , thank you

Comment: @ DontKnowMuchBut Getting Better  @MadProgrammer ty i got solution i wrote manually code. Should i post it?

Comment: post it if you still need help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to implement the isCellEditable at the DTB:

```
new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
) {
     @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
         return col != 3; //Third column is not editable
     }
}
```

By the way, you need to implement your own TableModel, you you see more problems while using the DefaultTableModel.